# Randomly select X number of lists from a list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, random

I have something like the following:

```
pen = [1, 2, 3, 4]
pencil = [2,3,4,5]
paper = [3,4,5,6]
group_of_items = [pen, pencil, paper]
```

I want to randomly select a certain number of lists from this list of lists so that the result is something like this:

```
[pencil, pen]
```

I found the following from another question (altered to match my situation).

```
import random

pen = [1, 2, 3, 4]
pencil = [2,3,4,5]
paper = [3,4,5,6]

group_of_items = [pen, pencil, paper]

num_to_select = 2
list_of_random_items = random.sample(group_of_items, num_to_select)
print(list_of_random_items)
```

It gives something like this.

```
[[2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

So, it's close but no cigar. I also found this.

```
import numpy as np

pen = [1, 2, 3, 4]
pencil = [2,3,4,5]
paper = [3,4,5,6]
group_of_items = [pen, pencil, paper]
num_to_select = 2

random_list = np.random.choice(group_of_items, num_to_select, replace=False)

print(random_list)
```

But it doesn't work with a list of lists (multi-dimensional).

**How can I accomplish my goal?**

*Oh, and I don't want any repeats.*

Note: my coding experience is rather limited. I mostly copy and paste what I find online, only making small changes.

***Edit***: The above is simply a quickly thrown together test. What I've built is a Twitter tweet bot using PythonAnywhere. It works wonderfully as is, but I want to add a more random functionality to it.

I have lists of tweets in a Google spreadsheet that I pull over to a Python list, like so:

```
quotes = tweet_sheet.col_values(3)
```

I have several lists like this that I put together in one master list of lists. But I don't want to tweet from every list every time I run the program.

Right now I use something like this.

```
sources = [tips,feed,quotes... etc...
```

I want to pick x number of lists from the master list of lists to use when the program runs. (That's worded kind of funny)

I'm guessing from the comments so far that what I have above would work. With a little more tweaking of the rest of the code, that is.

Comment: How is that result not what you want? Lists will not print the variable names.

Comment: Could you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: unless you handle data at string level, you won't be able to do that.

Comment: I do more processing after this code snippet in which I use the list names. Before trying this I've simply hard coded my own random selection of the lists. Was simply wondering if there was a way to do it more efficiently.

Comment: @MarkLee This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Maybe you should tell us what you are actually trying to do because there is probably a much better way to accomplish it.

Comment: Keep a `dict` of strings to lists, then randomly select form a list of those strings like you did above, then use the `dict` as a map from string to list.

Comment: I added an edit to the question with more details.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Never worked with dictionaries, though I have browsed the documentation. I think I understand what you are saying, but I don't know how to put that together. Could you share a quick example?

Comment: But Mark, *you are selecting a random sample of the lists*. How is your example "close but no cigar?" A python list will not remember the names of the variables that were used to build it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think I understand. I don't need the names of the lists. Cart before the horse situation I guess. Over thinking it as usual.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using dictionaries:

```
>>> pen = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> pencil = [2,3,4,5]
>>> paper = [3,4,5,6]
>>> item_dict = {'pen':pen, 'pencil':pencil, 'paper':paper}
>>> import random
>>> item_names = list(item_dict.keys())
>>> item_names
['pencil', 'pen', 'paper']
>>> sample = random.sample(item_names,2)
>>> sample
['pencil', 'pen']
>>> item_dict[sample[0]]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> item_dict[sample[1]]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So now you have an association between *strings* and *lists*:

```
>>> "The first list sampled was {}. Here's the list {}".format(sample[0], item_dict[sample[0]])
"The first list sampled was pencil. Here's the list [2, 3, 4, 5]"
>>>
```

Comment: Very nice. From the comments I don't think I need this level of specificity, but it's a nice clean example that might help someone in the future. Thanks for putting it together.

Answer (score 0):

If you definetly expect to be returned a list of random selected lists you can use the python native random.choices()

```
import random
pen = [1, 2, 3, 4]
pencil = [2,3,4,5]
paper = [3,4,5,6]
group_of_items = [pen, pencil, paper]
print(group_of_items)

sampling = random.choices(group_of_items, k=2)
print("sampling with choices() ", sampling)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
sampling with choices()  [[2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```